# Micropython (v1.20) crashes on an ESP32 with Guru Meditation Error

Tags: esp32, micropython

I have a ESP32 running MicroPython v1.20 and I'm recently seeing this crash happening sporadically (or at least I can't relate it to a specific function).

The ESP is using SD card via the SSD 1-bit interface, is connected to an I2S amplifier, uses ADC and a few leds (neopixel) and buttons. All these components I've worked with in the past, and using the same software drivers.

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40120e10  PS      : 0x00060830  A0      : 0x80149120  A1      : 0x3ffce2a0  
A2      : 0x3ffee8c0  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000001  A5      : 0x3ffce35c  
A6      : 0x3ffed5d4  A7      : 0x00000008  A8      : 0x80120e10  A9      : 0x3ffce280  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x49742400  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x3ffce360  
A14     : 0x3f4061c0  A15     : 0x0000000e  SAR     : 0x0000001e  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x0000000a  LBEG    : 0x4000c46c  LEND    : 0x4000c477  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace:0x40120e0d:0x3ffce2a00x4014911d:0x3ffce2c0 0x400be95a:0x3ffce2e0  |<-CORRUPTED




ELF file SHA256: 953126fe619512f2

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x1e (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:4396
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:13884
load:0x40080400,len:3340
entry 0x40080618
```

It's a bit too cryptic for me, is anyone more familiar and can at least give a hint as for where the problem is? or what causes the crash? I'll try to eliminate problems from there but I'm currently completely in the dark...

Comment: In theory there's almost nothing your Python program could to cause this kind of crash. There's a possibility that you're surfacing a bug in MicroPython. You might try an older release of the firmware just to see if it behaves differently. It's also possible that you're running out of memory and something inside Python isn't catching it. You could `import gc` and `print(gc.mem_free())` to check free memory. Also I2S support is currently a "technical preview" so it might be trashy. You could try your program with I2S commented out and see if it still crashes.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it's something deep under my code.. But I'll try compiling a previous version (1.19.1 was with us for quite some time) and see what happens. I'll also check without the audio, although I've had a few other projects that used the same MAX98257 card and I2S, so I feel safe with this.